# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: hello.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2

Tags: discord.py, discord-buttons

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: TypeError: hello..() takes 1 positional
> argument but 2 were givven

i try to run discord.py code but this error cames

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hello", components = [
        [Button(label="Hi", style="3", emoji = "", custom_id="button1"), Button(label="Bye", style="4", emoji = "", custom_id="button2")]
        ])
    interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "button1")
    await interaction.send(content = "Button clicked!", ephemeral=False)
```

[code source](https://github.com/afazio1/robotic-nation-proj/blob/master/projects/discord-bot/components.py)

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include the relevant code in a code block, not a link.

Comment: As for the issue at hand, please include the exact text you are calling the function with (in Discord itself). From the error, it looks like you may be passing in some unexpected arguments to the command.